# how to create a different head pointer for a inside a LinkedList inside a LinkedList ? [C]

Tags: pointers, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Hi I'm and a new computer science student, currently trying to learn C++ language.

I'm trying to create a program that have a nested linkedlist, where the main linkedlist contains the customer's name, Id number, a head and tail pointer (unique to each customer node) for a secondary linkedlist which contains string that represents a line of note for the corresponding customer.

Example of what I'm trying to create :

main linked list :

NULL <-[HEAD POINTER]<-> William/1228  <->  stefan/1344  <->  andre/1566 <-> [TAIL pointer]-> NULL

where the first node (William/1228) have a secondary linked list :

NULL <-[Head_notes] <-> "likes to order dessert" <-> "alergic to nut" <-> [tail_notes]-> NULL

The problem is I cannot create different head pointer for each customer node, so each customer have the same shared note and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define  SIZE 20

struct notes{
    //contained attributes
    char string[SIZE];
    
    //pointer to other nodes
    struct notes *prev = NULL;
    struct notes *next = NULL;
};

struct node{
    //contained attributes
    char customer_name[SIZE];
    int id_number;
    
    //pointer to other nodes
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    
    //head and tail pointer to notes;
    struct notes *head_notes;
    struct notes *tail_notes;
    struct notes *curr_notes;
    
    void showNotes(){
        printf("==========================================================\n");
        printf("Name        : %s\n", customer_name);
        printf("ID number   : %d\n", id_number);
        printf("Notes       :\n");
        printf("==========================================================\n");
        curr_notes = head_notes;
        while(curr_notes != NULL){
            printf("  -) %s\n", curr_notes->string);
            curr_notes = curr_notes->next;
        }
        printf("==========================================================\n");
    }
    void addNotes(char string[]){
        struct notes *temp = (struct notes*)malloc(sizeof(struct notes));
        strcpy(temp->string, string);
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->next = NULL;
        
        if(this->head_notes == NULL){
            this->head_notes = temp;
            this->tail_notes = temp;
        }else{
            temp->prev = this->tail_notes;
            this->tail_notes->next = temp;
            this->tail_notes = temp;
        }
        this->tail_notes->next = NULL;
        this->head_notes->prev = NULL;
    }
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *tail = NULL;
struct node *curr;

void push(struct node* new_node){
    //if linkedlist is empty
    if(head == NULL){
        head = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }
    //insert from tail
    else{
        new_node->prev = tail;
        tail->next = new_node;
        tail = new_node;
    }
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail->next = NULL;
    return;
}

void printList(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        curr->showNotes();
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

struct node *create(){
    struct node *customer   = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    customer->head_notes    = NULL;
    customer->tail_notes    = NULL;
    customer->next          = NULL;
    customer->tail_notes    = NULL;
    return customer;
}

void Input(){
    //decalring variable
    char    key_pressed, string[SIZE];
    int     length, id;
    bool    repeat, ask_name, ask_notes;
    repeat  = true;
    
    //creating and initialize the Node for customer's data
    struct node *customer   = create();

    //starting main loop
    while(repeat){
        //initialize necessary variable
        strcpy(string ,"");
        length    = 0;
        ask_name  = true;
        
        //loop to ask customer's name
        system("cls");
        printf("\n==========================\n\nInsert Name : %s", string);
        while(ask_name){
            if(kbhit()){
                key_pressed = getch(); fflush(stdin);
                //user press enter
                if(key_pressed == 13  && length < SIZE){
                    if(strcmp(string, "END") == 0) return;
                    string[length] = '\0';
                    strcpy(customer->customer_name, string); //inserting customer name to the node
                    strcpy(string, "");
                    length = 0;
                    ask_name = false;
                }
                //user press backspace
                else if(key_pressed == 8){
                    if(length != 0) length--;
                    string[length] = '\0';  
                }
                //user press normal character
                else if (key_pressed >= 32 && key_pressed <= 126 && length < SIZE){
                    string[length] = key_pressed;
                    length++;
                    string[length] = '\0';
                }
                
                //refresh screen
                system("cls");
                printf("\n==========================\n\nInsert Name : %s\n", string);
                if(length == SIZE) printf("[Name Limit is 30 Character]\n");
            }
        }
        
        //asking for id number
        system("cls");
        printf("\n==========================\n\n");
        printf("Insert Name : %s\n", customer->customer_name);
        printf("Insert ID Number : ");
        scanf("%d", &id);getchar();
        customer->id_number = id;
        
        //asking notes
        system("cls");
        printf("\n==========================\n\nNotes :\n");
        customer->showNotes();
        ask_notes = true;
        while(ask_notes){
            if(kbhit()){
                key_pressed = getch(); fflush(stdin);
                //user press enter
                if(key_pressed == 13 || length == SIZE){
                    if(strcmp(string, "END") == 0){
                        strcpy(string, "");
                        length = 0;
                        ask_notes = false;
                        continue;
                    } 
                    string[length] = '\0';
                    customer->addNotes(string);
                    strcpy(string, "");
                    length = 0;
                }
                //user press backspace
                else if(key_pressed == 8){
                    if(length != 0) length--;
                    string[length] = '\0';  
                }
                //user press normal character
                else if (key_pressed >= 32 && key_pressed <= 126){
                    string[length] = key_pressed;
                    length++;
                    string[length] = '\0';
                }
                
                //refresh screen
                system("cls");
                printf("==========================\n\nNotes : %s\n\n", string);
                customer->showNotes();
            }
        }
        push(customer);
    }
}

int main(){
    Input();
    printList();
    printf("DONE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid C code. In C you may not define functions inside a structure definition.

Comment: This is not valid C code so I assume you are actually coding C++. Be aware  that there is no such language as "C/C++". Those are two different languages. Please review your language tag.